# Not able to zip files which is present in s3 bucket using aws-s3-zipper and node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to zip files specifically .gz format in aws s3 bucket. I didn't got any proper example for this. Does any one have any suggestion for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simple bash script using AWS CLI which will get file from S3 --> zip it and put it back on S3

Comment: i am using aws-lamda  along with node js to achieve this.can we use the same what you have suggested with aws-lamda.

Comment: we cannot do my suggested solution with lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the file, Lambda might not be the right tool. That said, if your file isn't too large, this should work:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();
const body = s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(passThrough);

const s3Out = {
    Key: key,
    Bucket: bucket,
    Body: body
}

await s3.upload(s3Out).promise();
```

zlib is an included module, no need to install anything, just `require` it.